# Batch file copying issue

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I'm having trouble making a batch file that copies files. Sometimes it says that the directories exist, other times it says that it can not perform a cyclic copy.

```
@ECHO off

ECHO Please use quotes with directories

ECHO.



IF NOT EXIST Pictures (MD Pictures) > NUL



:start

SET /P From=Copy from:

IF NOT EXIST %From% (ECHO No such directory

                     ECHO.

                     goto start)

XCOPY /s %From% Pictures

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to create a directory, that already exists, `md` tells you. You can suppress it with

```
md pictures 2>nul
```

The parameter `/s` with `xcopy` tells  the computer to copy subdirectories and their content  too. So you would make a copy of a copy of a copy of a copy.... (called cyclic copy). To avoid this, don't use `/s` or make sure, the destination directory is outside the directory-tree, you want to copy.

Comment: How would I check that the targeted directory is outside of the destination directory?

Comment: Don't check before. `xcopy` will give an errorlevel of `4`. After the `xcopy`line do: `if %errorlevel%==4 echo wrong & goto start`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it: xcopy creates the folder by itself and the slash at the end of the target path stops it from prompting you.

The slash at the if exist "folder\" is used to detect a folder on a local drive, and not a file.

`Stephan's` answer tells you how to avoid a cyclic copy error.

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Please use quotes with directories
ECHO.
:start
SET /P From=Copy from:

IF exist "%From%\" (
      XCOPY /s %From% "Pictures\" 
) else (
      ECHO No such directory
      ECHO.
      goto start
)
pause
```